# program of Recursion for Maximum Independent Set in a Graph

Tags: c++, python, c, algorithm, data-structures

I am getting difficulty in writing a program for the above mentioned problem.. I have the following graph....

```
A-----B------C       D
A is connected to B
B is connected to C
D is connected with no body!! 
The maximum Independent set in this is {A,C, D}...
```

The Adjacency Matrix for the graph is below:-

[image: Adjacency Matrix]

I drew the following decision tree inorder to solve the problem:-

[image: Recursion Tree]

- The first element of each node is the index.
- The second element of each node is the set which store independent elements of the graph.
- The left branch says that i will not consider the element, and the right branch says that I will consider the element at index specified by first element of the node.

So as you can see clearly, at each node, I haven't considered the element specified by first element index of the node, and I have consider the element whether it can be inserted in the independent set.

I want to write up a program for this in Python!! I am a newbie, and just still in early stages of implementing the program through recursion.

kindly help!!

I wrote the following code:- but it doesn't looks nice to me.. Its working somehow.. Please experiences People could put in your comments.. I am still learning in recursion..

```
def maxset(tab, i, set):
    global numcalls
    numcalls += 1
    if i == 0:
        flag = 0
        for s in set:
            if tab[i][s]:
                return 0
        if i not in set:
            set.append(i)
        return len(set)

    without_i = maxset(tab, i-1, set)

    flag = 0
    for s in set:
        if tab[i][s]:
            return without_i
    if i not in set:
        set.append(i)
    with_i = maxset(tab,i-1,set)
    return max(without_i, with_i)


tab = [[0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
#tab = [[0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0]]
set = []
numVertIndex = 3 #### 0,1,2,3
numcalls = 0
print(maxset(tab, numVertIndex, set))
print(set)
print (numcalls)
```

Comment: Try solving the maximal clique first.

Answer (score 3):

There is a well known and simple algorithm to solve this problem:

1. Initially color all your vertices green.
2. Find a green vertex.  Color it's neighbors red.
3. For every red vertex, color it's green neighbors red. (Here's the recursion part)
4. When there are no more red vertices with green neighbors, the set of red vertices determines a maximally connected component.
5. Repeat from 2 until all vertices are red and all components are discovered.

Now that you know all the components, you can choose the one with the most vertices (i.e. the highest order maximally connected sub-graph).

Comment: Yes, there mite be the simplest algorithms available.. But i was first trying to solve this so that i have some solution handy.. And then will go and work it out the complex one!! Can you provide me the code for above whch i mentioned..? i am facing difficulty in writing recursive code!! :(

Comment: Post the code you've tried that didn't work and then people can help. Don't ask people to write code for you.

Comment: I have posted the code which i just completed.... Please provide inputs as in how can i improve on it?

Comment: @DeepYellow the OP is asking about maximal *independent set* (dual to clique), and not about *connected components*. There is no known polynomial algorithm for what the OP's asking.

Answer (score 0):

As for your code:

1. It has one critical error: `set` is never copied. Usually it is ok, but this is not the case. Let's see your code. After computing of `without_i` the original set value could be modified. In this case computing of `with_i` uses incorrect set value. The simplest example of the case I could imagine is `tab = [[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0]]`.
2. Minor errors: `flag` is unused? Also `numcalls` seems to be created to simplify debugging. So I exclude it in my code example.
3. It seems to me that interface of your function is not convenient. User has to create his own `set` variable and manually specify problem size. So in my code example I wrapped the original function into the one with interface I would like to use. Actually you can go further and explore the ways of adjacency declaration. For example, adjacency lists could be more convenient than matrices.

My code example:

```
def maxset( tab ):
    def maxset_detail(tab, i, set):
        if any( tab[i][s] for s in set ):
            return i and maxset_detail(tab, i-1, set) or 0
        if (i == 0):
            set.append(i)
            return len(set)
        set_copy = set[:] + [i]
        without_i = maxset_detail(tab, i-1, set)
        with_i = maxset_detail(tab, i-1, set_copy)
        if ( with_i > without_i ):
            set[:] = set_copy
            return with_i
        else:
            return without_i
    set = []
    maxset_detail(tab, len(tab)-1, set )
    return set
```